# Insert a hyperlink in src

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build a simple playground that works like plunker. The way plunker executes a set of files (eg, html, css, js) is that it saves the files in their sever, then replaces for example `<script src="script.js">` by `<script src="script.js">` where `script.js` points to `https://run.plnkr.co/OTpc0NRkab8GGMyY/script.js`:

[image]

My question is how the address `https://run.plnkr.co/OTpc0NRkab8GGMyY/script.js` is inserted into `<script src="script.js">`, so that `iframe` could recognise this external link. I tried `<script src="<a href='https://...'>script.js</a>"></script>`, but it does not work.

Could anyone help?

Comment: This is almost assuredly done server-side.

Comment: the `script.js` resides in server's / project's root directory. so they don't need to use literal url.

Comment: @siam but the content of the iframe is evaluated in the browser, where is the indication that says "the content is evaluated in the context of that server's / project's root directory"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to worry about that. Using `<script src="script.js">` is enough, provided that you store `script.js` file in the same directory as `main.html`.

I've tried creating a simple static website using IIS, notice the `script` tag:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

[image: screenshot]

*UPDATE: when using iframe*

`main.html` uses `<iframe src="index.html"></iframe>`

`index.html` still uses `<script src="script.js"></script>`

**Notice** that the path is updated with the new subfolder

[image]

Therefore: since plunkr uses `https://run.plnkr.co/uiO6VFCDHhBdHP8h/{FILENAME}`
even when using iframe, we can safely assume that main page and iframe index.html is in the same directory, same with the js/css files

Comment: Do you think, plunker stores `index.html` in a directory (same directory as `script.js`), and then inject the content to iframe to evaluate? I don't see the evidence...

Comment: path: https://run.plnkr.co/uiO6VFCDHhBdHP8h is the root directory of the webpage. https://run.plnkr.co/uiO6VFCDHhBdHP8h/index.html is the `index.html` file in the root directory and thus https://run.plnkr.co/uiO6VFCDHhBdHP8h/script.js is the `script.js` file in the root directory. by viewing page source of https://run.plnkr.co/uiO6VFCDHhBdHP8h you can see the raw code there, there is no formatting or whatsoever of the `script` src:

view-source:https://run.plnkr.co/uiO6VFCDHhBdHP8h

Comment: Do you have access to all these files? It always shows "Not Found" after entering their URL in a browser tab...

Comment: what files? the links in my comment? i havent saved them. you can always open the script src link in dev tools to new tab.

Comment: I see... I agree with you that `index.html` and `script.js`, etc. are all saved in a temporary folder, and the link `<script src="script.js">` will automatically work. My last question is: plunker does not seem to have your `main.html`, it just injects the content of `index.html` to the iframe and shows in Dev Tools `<iframe src="about:blank"...`. How does the iframe know the specific temporary folder? I don't see any evidence while inspecting the page...

Comment: `src="about:blank"` is a temporary src. they may have some script that updates that on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://run.plnkr.co/OTpc0NRkab8GGMyY/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: But will it look like `<script src="script.js">` like the right hand side of my image?

Comment: it should but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things here.
The anchor element (`<a href='https://...'>script.js</a>`) can be used to display clickable links on the page, it is not possible to put this into the `src` attribute of the script tag.
The script tag's `src` attribute must be provided with an URL, for example:

```
<script src="https://run.plnkr.co/OTpc0NRkab8GGMyY/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: But will it look like `<script src="script.js">` like the right hand side of my image?